# glob for all folders within a folder except one named folder

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

I am writing my Karma conf based on

http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/preprocessors.html

The key for the preprocessor is a glob string.

This works for all folders within the build folder:

```
build/**/!(*.spec|*.bundle|*.min).js
```

However, I don't want all folders. I wanted folder 1,2,4,5 NOT folder 3

Can I write that in a single string (as seems to be required by karma)?

Something like

```
build/(folder1|folder2|folder4|folder5)/!(*.spec|*.bundle|*.min).js
```

or even better

```
build/** but not folder 3/!(*.spec|*.bundle|*.min).js
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This covers it

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/issues/13

Quoting it

You can make this work using brace expansion. For @chevalric's case, the following pattern will do it:

```
src/*/{*.js,!(test)/**/*.js}
```

This expands to two patterns:

```
src/*/*.js              # Match files in the module root
src/*/!(test)/**/*.js   # Match files in all subfolders except test/
```

Also it later says ..

```
src/*/!(test)/**/*.js
```

worked

However, for me, I could not test that this worked for various reasons.